# Getting imported json data into a data frame

Tags: json, r, import, dataframe

I have a file containing over 1500 json objects that I want to work with in R. I've been able to import the data as a list, but am having trouble coercing it into a useful structure. I want to create a data frame containing a row for each json object and a column for each key:value pair.

I've recreated my situation with this small, fake data set:

```
[{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age (y)":24,"height (cm)":182,"wieght (kg)":74.8,"score":null},
{"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age (y)":30,"height (cm)":170,"wieght (kg)":70.1,"score":500},
{"name":"Smith, Joan","group":"Yellow","age (y)":41,"height (cm)":169,"wieght (kg)":60,"score":null},
{"name":"Brown, Sam","group":"Green","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":183,"wieght (kg)":75,"score":865},
{"name":"Jones, Larry","group":"Green","age (y)":31,"height (cm)":178,"wieght (kg)":83.9,"score":221},
{"name":"Murray, Seth","group":"Red","age (y)":35,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":76.2,"score":413},
{"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Yellow","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":164,"wieght (kg)":68,"score":902}]
```

Some features of the data:

- The objects all contain the same number of key:value pairs although
  some of the values are null
- There are two non-numeric columns per object (name and group)
- name is the unique identifier, there are 10 or so groups
- many of the name and group entires contain spaces, commas and other punctuation.

Based on this question: [R list(structure(list())) to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508986/r-liststructurelist-to-data-frame), I tried the following:

```
json_file <- "test.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
asFrame <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(json_data, as.data.frame))
```

With both my real data and this fake data, the last line give me this error:

```
Error in data.frame(name = "Doe, John", group = "Red", `age (y)` = 24,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is very simple if you use either `library(jsonlite)` or `library(jsonify)`

Both of these handle the `null` values and converts them to `NA`, and they preserve the data types.

#### Data

```
json_file <-  '[{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age (y)":24,"height (cm)":182,"wieght (kg)":74.8,"score":null},
{"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age (y)":30,"height (cm)":170,"wieght (kg)":70.1,"score":500},
{"name":"Smith, Joan","group":"Yellow","age (y)":41,"height (cm)":169,"wieght (kg)":60,"score":null},
{"name":"Brown, Sam","group":"Green","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":183,"wieght (kg)":75,"score":865},
{"name":"Jones, Larry","group":"Green","age (y)":31,"height (cm)":178,"wieght (kg)":83.9,"score":221},
{"name":"Murray, Seth","group":"Red","age (y)":35,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":76.2,"score":413},
{"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Yellow","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":164,"wieght (kg)":68,"score":902}]'
```

#### jsonlite

```
library(jsonlite)
jsonlite::fromJSON( json_file )
#           name  group age (y) height (cm) wieght (kg) score
# 1    Doe, John    Red      24         182        74.8    NA
# 2    Doe, Jane  Green      30         170        70.1   500
# 3  Smith, Joan Yellow      41         169        60.0    NA
# 4   Brown, Sam  Green      22         183        75.0   865
# 5 Jones, Larry  Green      31         178        83.9   221
# 6 Murray, Seth    Red      35         172        76.2   413
# 7    Doe, Jane Yellow      22         164        68.0   902

str( jsonlite::fromJSON( json_file ) )
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ name       : chr  "Doe, John" "Doe, Jane" "Smith, Joan" "Brown, Sam" ...
# $ group      : chr  "Red" "Green" "Yellow" "Green" ...
# $ age (y)    : int  24 30 41 22 31 35 22
# $ height (cm): int  182 170 169 183 178 172 164
# $ wieght (kg): num  74.8 70.1 60 75 83.9 76.2 68
# $ score      : int  NA 500 NA 865 221 413 902
```

#### jsonify

```
library(jsonify)
jsonify::from_json( json_file )
#           name  group age (y) height (cm) wieght (kg) score
# 1    Doe, John    Red      24         182        74.8    NA
# 2    Doe, Jane  Green      30         170        70.1   500
# 3  Smith, Joan Yellow      41         169        60.0    NA
# 4   Brown, Sam  Green      22         183        75.0   865
# 5 Jones, Larry  Green      31         178        83.9   221
# 6 Murray, Seth    Red      35         172        76.2   413
# 7    Doe, Jane Yellow      22         164        68.0   90


str( jsonify::from_json( json_file ) )
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ name       : chr  "Doe, John" "Doe, Jane" "Smith, Joan" "Brown, Sam" ...
# $ group      : chr  "Red" "Green" "Yellow" "Green" ...
# $ age (y)    : int  24 30 41 22 31 35 22
# $ height (cm): int  182 170 169 183 178 172 164
# $ wieght (kg): num  74.8 70.1 60 75 83.9 76.2 68
# $ score      : int  NA 500 NA 865 221 413 902
```

Comment: I ran the exact same code as you, but when I run `fromJSON` it returns a list, not a data frame. How did you get it to return a data frame?

Comment: @Alexander - I still get a `data.frame`. Make sure you're using `jsonlite::fromJSON`

Answer (score 56):

You just need to replace your NULLs with NAs:

```
require(RJSONIO)    

json_file <-  '[{"name":"Doe, John","group":"Red","age (y)":24,"height (cm)":182,"wieght (kg)":74.8,"score":null},
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Green","age (y)":30,"height (cm)":170,"wieght (kg)":70.1,"score":500},
    {"name":"Smith, Joan","group":"Yellow","age (y)":41,"height (cm)":169,"wieght (kg)":60,"score":null},
    {"name":"Brown, Sam","group":"Green","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":183,"wieght (kg)":75,"score":865},
    {"name":"Jones, Larry","group":"Green","age (y)":31,"height (cm)":178,"wieght (kg)":83.9,"score":221},
    {"name":"Murray, Seth","group":"Red","age (y)":35,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":76.2,"score":413},
    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Yellow","age (y)":22,"height (cm)":164,"wieght (kg)":68,"score":902}]'


json_file <- fromJSON(json_file)

json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
```

Once you have a non-null value for each element, you can call `rbind` without getting an error:

```
do.call("rbind", json_file)
     name           group    age (y) height (cm) wieght (kg) score
[1,] "Doe, John"    "Red"    "24"    "182"       "74.8"      NA   
[2,] "Doe, Jane"    "Green"  "30"    "170"       "70.1"      "500"
[3,] "Smith, Joan"  "Yellow" "41"    "169"       "60"        NA   
[4,] "Brown, Sam"   "Green"  "22"    "183"       "75"        "865"
[5,] "Jones, Larry" "Green"  "31"    "178"       "83.9"      "221"
[6,] "Murray, Seth" "Red"    "35"    "172"       "76.2"      "413"
[7,] "Doe, Jane"    "Yellow" "22"    "164"       "68"        "902"
```

Comment: I am surprised that there is no better function to do this. (for XML there are functions like XMLtoDataFrame) so JSONtoDataFrame would be great

Comment: @userJT - there's `jsonlite::fromJSON` - handles the NULLs and simplifies to a `data.frame`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37739735/5977215)

Comment: this convert the json_file into matrix, not a data frame. How do I get a data.frame?

Comment: @TSR: `data.frame(do.call("rbind", json_file))`

Answer (score 2):

To remove null values use parameter nullValue

```
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file, nullValue = NA)
asFrame <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(json_data, as.data.frame))
```

this way there won´t be any unnecessary quotes in your output

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rjson)
Lines <- readLines("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json") 
business <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(Lines, fromJSON)))
```

You may try this to load JSON data into R

Answer (score 0):

```
dplyr::bind_rows(fromJSON(file_name))
```

Comment: which `fromJson` function are you using? If it's from `jsonlite`, then the `dplyr::bind_rows` is redundant. If it's from `rjson` then your solutino errors on the provided data.

Comment: don't remember; things must have changed

Answer (score 0):

Changing the package from `rjson` to `jsonlite` fixed it for me.

So instead of this:

```
fromAPIPlantsPages <- rjson::fromJSON(content(apiGetPlants,type="text",encoding = "UTF-8"))

dfPlantenAPI <- as.data.frame(fromAPIPlantsPages)
```

I changed it to this:

```
fromAPIPlantsPages <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(apiGetPlants,type="text",encoding = "UTF-8"))

dfPlantenAPI <- as.data.frame(fromAPIPlantsPages)
```