# How can I run an example of npm

Tags: javascript, npm

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180300/4477894) is a nice example on how to convert a complete json to csv.

I installed the program using `npm install json-2-csv`

I tried to take a run at the example. I made a js file but I can't run it. How can I run it to see in action how it works?

It is the example provided for  json-2-csv page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
    var converter = require('json-2-csv');

var documents = [
    {
        Make: 'Nissan',
        Model: 'Murano',
        Year: '2013',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '7106',
            Trim: 'S AWD'
        }
    },
    {
        Make: 'BMW',
        Model: 'X5',
        Year: '2014',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '3287',
            Trim: 'M'
        }
    }
];

var json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(csv);
};

converter.json2csv(documents, json2csvCallback);

    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code please?

Comment: You can't use require() in HTML... You have to use  a <script> tag to include .js files.

Comment: I use the script tag I think

Comment: Is it possible to give an example on how to be my js file because I newbie to web development use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `node` and `npm` installed...

You need to forget about the HTML markup.  That's what node is complaining about.

- Create a folder called something like `example`.
- In that folder, run `npm install json-2-csv`.
- Create a file called `example.js` and paste in the following.  Basically, just the script from your question...

```js
var converter = require('json-2-csv');

var documents = [
    {
        Make: 'Nissan',
        Model: 'Murano',
        Year: '2013',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '7106',
            Trim: 'S AWD'
        }
    },
    {
        Make: 'BMW',
        Model: 'X5',
        Year: '2014',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '3287',
            Trim: 'M'
        }
    }
];

var json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(csv);
};

converter.json2csv(documents, json2csvCallback);
```

- Save the file in that folder.
- In that folder, run `node example.js`.

That's it!  The program will print out the data in CSV format.

Comment: Hey it works with your steps. Thank you. Can I write this data from console csv to a csv file?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest is just run `node example.js > output.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is called myFile.js, run the following from terminal in the same directory as your JS file:

```
node myFile.js
```

This assumes you've installed NodeJS which you can install from NodeJS.org.

Comment: Yes I got the nodejs but when I run the command it gives me back SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Could be possible to provide a full example? How my js file have to be, what steps should I do and how to save the results to a new csv file?

Comment: Can you post your JS code so we can look at it? Tough to see your syntax error without.