# JSON to CSV converter in R jsonlite

Tags: json, r, csv, dataframe

I am trying to convert a JSON file to dataframe using jsonlite library in R. Unfortunately many columns in the dataframe are containing lists of unequal length in them.

```
library(jsonlite)
a <- fromJSON(file.choose(),flatten=TRUE,simplifyDataFrame=TRUE)</b></br>
```

I am not able to attach the sample file as it too huge. Is there any way to overcome this in a generic way? If anything specific with this file please let me know

```
{
"qqqqqq": {
"Id": "444444",
"AddDate": "2015-04-08T22:48:26.287-05:00",
"Person": {
"Id": "666666",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER",
"AddDate": "2013-01-05T18:08:41-06:00",
"PostalAddress": {
"Id": "777777",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER",
"AddDate": "2013-01-05T18:08:41-06:00" 
},
"PostalAddress": {
"Id": "234234234",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER",
"AddDate": "2013-01-05T18:08:41-06:00" 
} 
} 
},
"qqqqqq": {
"Id": "66666",
"AddDate": "2015-04-08T22:48:26.287-05:00",
"Person": {
"Id": "33333",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER",
"AddDate": "2013-01-05T18:08:41-06:00",
"Phone": "9494949494"
"PostalAddress": {
"Id": "7878787",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER" 
},
"PostalAddress": {
"Id": "545454",
"AddUserId": "SYSTEM_USER",
"AddDate": "2013-01-05T18:08:41-06:00" 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175276/convert-json-to-csv-format?rq=1

Comment: Can you suggest an approach using R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339805/converting-json-format-to-csv-to-upload-data-table-in-r-to-produce-d3-bubble-cha?rq=1