# from json.gz2 to R

Tags: json, r

I have a file with `json.gz2` extension and I want to transform it in a dataset. Its structure is as follows:

```
{
 "reviewerID": "A2SUAM1J3GNN3B",
 "asin": "0000013714",
 "reviewerName": "J. McDonald",
 "helpful": [2, 3],
 "reviewText": "I bought this for my husband who plays the piano.  He is having a wonderful time playing these old hymns.  The music  is at times hard to read because we think the book was published for singing from more than playing from.  Great purchase though!",
 "overall": 5.0,
 "summary": "Heavenly Highway Hymns",
 "unixReviewTime": 1252800000,
 "reviewTime": "09 13, 2009"
}
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip

def parse(path):
  g = gzip.open(path, 'rb')
  for l in g:
    yield eval(l)

def getDF(path):
  i = 0
  df = {}
  for d in parse(path):
    df[i] = d
    i += 1
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')

df = getDF('file.json.gz')
```