# Retrieving data in R from Import.io API using Rcurl?

Tags: json, r, rcurl, import.io, rjson

Im trying to retrieve data from an import.io 'connector' API.

Basically, i've trained the extractor to the structure of a given website, and I want to import the data from within R using this approach:
1) Retrieve the Json results from the API
2) Save each query-result into a given dataframe

**My plan was to use RCurl for querying the API-link:**
https://api.import.io/store/connector/9128b4e0-9ae2-4232-b202-c1e8766ed01f/_query?input=webpage/url:[ENCODED URL]&&_apikey=[API-KEY]

```
require(Rcurl)
Raw.Data <- curl::curl(url = "https://api.import.io/store/connector/9128b4e0-9ae2-4232-b202-c1e8766ed01f/_query?input=webpage/url:[ENCODED URL]&&_apikey=[API-KEY]")
```

**And after that, use Rjson for reading the retrieved data into a dataframe:**

```
require(rjson)
FromJson_To_DataFrame <-(Raw.data)
```

There is something missing because I am getting errors, but i cannot figure out what it is, and if it is possible at all like this. Hints would be greatly aprecaiated!

Cheers from DK

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting? Also you have two ampersands in your query string `input=webpage/url:[ENCODED URL]&&_apikey=[API-KEY]` which might be causing an issue.

Comment: @Bam4d thanks for reply! Youre right, the error was due to the two &&.. Now my next problem is to store the data in a dataframe which seems like its not so straight forward as just:

**require(rjson)
FromJson_To_DataFrame <-(Raw.data)**

Comment: I don't know much about R sorry, but I did find this which might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r

The data format here is the same as that which is used in import.io datasets, so it will be a good start I hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem, which is fairly straightforward. The json object retrieved from the import.io API can be changed in to columns in a DF by accesing it via $:

```
library(httr)   
output <- get(https://api.import.io/store/connector/9128b4e0-9ae2-4232-b202-c1e8766ed01f/_query?input=webpage/url:[ENCODED URL]&&_apikey=[API-KEY])

result <- content(output)

vector1 <- result$results$variable1
vector2 <- result$results$variable2
```

and then you can cbind them to a dataframe if you need to.