# R - opening a json file

Tags: json, r

So I have looked at many other posts and have tried what they said with this link being the closest solution:

[Getting imported json data into a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r)

So I have a JSON file that took a data frame and saved it. I open it with

```
json_data <- fromJSON(file = test.json)
```

It gives me a list of 16 with the fields that I want in `[1:300]`, so it looks like the data is there but I cant get it formatted to a new data frame with the fields in the columns and all the 300 data in the rows. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Tried `as.data.frame`? Or `do.call(cbind,listhing)`? Or **anything**?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+minimal+reproducible+example).

Comment: do.call(cbind,jsonfile) seems to have done it. Thank you so much.