# Importing Data from a json file in R

Tags: json, r

I have a json data file from which I want to import in R. I tried searching for similar blogs but either they are getting data from URLs or the syntax gave errors.

Let's say the name of the json file is "Jsdata.json"

How can i get the data from Jsdata.json to R and convert it into the excel/csv format for a better picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting imported json data into a data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: it would be appropriate to provide a sample `json` file, however I don't see how this is different from all of the examples where `.json` file is downloaded from a URL then parsed. You just substitute your file in place of the one that was downloaded.

Comment: Can you tell the syntax by which i can read that data from the json file and parse it in csv in the ways we have an excel? I am using  <br>  treview <- "filepath" <br>
json_data<- fromJSON(treview)

Comment: Sample data in that json file {"key":"type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit","doc_count":12},{"key":"type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit","doc_count":8}, {"key":"type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit","doc_count":9}

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the `file` parameter in `fromJSON`. `fromJSON(file = treview)` should work.

Comment: @Psidom, Hi, I tried using that but got the error- Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature ‘"missing", "missing"’ .... <br> Also, once we have the data in the dataframe, how can i parse it into excel format?

Comment: What json packages are your using?

Comment: I tried using both rjson and RJSONIO

Comment: Just made a show case using `rjson` package in the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To confirm, this is the output using `rjson` package. The `file` parameter has to be explicitly specified here, otherwise the function will treat it as a json string and throw an error.

```
myList = rjson::fromJSON(file = "JsData.json")
myList
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$key
# [1] "type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit"
# 
# [[1]]$doc_count
# [1] 12


# [[2]]
# [[2]]$key
# [1] "type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit"

# [[2]]$doc_count
# [1] 8


# [[3]]
# [[3]]$key
# [1] "type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit"

# [[3]]$doc_count
# [1] 9
```

In order to convert this to data frame, you can do:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, data.frame))

#                            key doc_count
# 1   type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit        12
# 2    type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit         8
# 3 type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit         9
```

Write the data frame as `csv` using `write.csv(..., sep = "\t")` and configure your excel so that the delimiter matches your `sep` here should work.

And the *JsData.json* data looks like this:

```
[{"key":"type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit","doc_count":12},
 {"key":"type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit","doc_count":8}, 
 {"key":"type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit","doc_count":9}]
```

Comment: Explicit calling worked. Thanks!. Can you also tell how can i parse this data to be useful in excel.

Comment: It's a little bit tricky to make your data fit with excel since you have comma in your data. But check the answer, it gives some clue to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Psidom. I received an error-- Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 <br><br> Not sure what am i doing wrong. I wrote this only-  do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, data.frame))

Comment: I am not sure what I can tell you. That command should have no problem to produce a data.frame assuming `myList` is exactly what we have in the first stage.