# JSON data to dataframe in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have a json file from which i am importing the data

```
myList = rjson::fromJSON(file = "JsData.json")
myList


[[1]]
[[1]]$key
[1] "type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit"
[[1]]$doc_count
[1] 12

[[2]]
[[2]]$key
[2] "type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit"
[[2]]$doc_count
[2] 8
```

But when I am trying to convert to a data frame by function below ,
`do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, data.frame))`

I am getting an error.-

`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

I need to parse this data so that it can be used in excel csv. I looked at the solution for [Getting imported json data into a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
 but the output is not coming in the proper usable format in excel.

And the JsData.json sample data looks like this:

`[{"key":"type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit","doc_count":12},
 {"key":"type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit","doc_count":8}, 
 {"key":"type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit","doc_count":9}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
require(jsonlite)
 s  ='[{"key":"type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit","doc_count":12}, 
      .......
        "key":"type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit","doc_count":9}]'

df <- fromJSON(s)
df

                             key doc_count
 1   type1|new york, ny|NYC|hit        12
 2    type1|omaha, ne|Omaha|hit         8
 3 type2|yuba city, ca|Yuba|hit         9
```

I don't know how you want to deal wiyh you key .....

Comment: I am reading it from a JSON file. The data which I have posted is a sample data of that file. Hence I am explicitly calling the fromJSON function else with your suggested method, I got the error <br>  argument "txt" is missing, with no default<br> The key column has pipe delimited data which i will covert into different columns in excel

Comment: Could you update you example with the problematic part ?

Comment: This was the exact one I was getting errors on. <br> myList = rjson::fromJSON(file = JSON file path) <br>  do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, data.frame)) <br> This is giving the error mentioned in the above question