# Extract data in columnar format from JSON in R

Tags: json, r

I want to extract data from the json object in R
R Package used tidyjson, magrittr, jsonlite

```
trial <- '[{ "KEYS": {"USER_ID": "1266", "MOBILE_NO": "9000000000"}}]'

trial %>%  
  gather_array %>% # stack as an array
  spread_values(USER_ID = jstring("KEYS.USER_ID"), 
MOBILE_NO = jstring("KEYs.MOBILE_NO")  )
```

Output of this code is not as required. Anyone with suggestions.

```
 document.id array.index USER_ID MOBILE_NO
1           1           1    <NA>      <NA>
```

Expected output:

```
 document.id array.index USER_ID MOBILE_NO
         1           1    1266     9000000000
```

Comment: if `trial` really is an array with many objects, adding a few more into the example along with the `library()` calls for the pkgs you used would enable folks to help you better.

Comment: Similar to example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 0):

`tidyjson` uses multi-parameter paths, rather than "dot-separated" paths, as you attempted.  You can really tackle this two ways:

Recommended, as it does not throw away the rest of the object:

```
trial <- '[{ "KEYS": {"USER_ID": "1266", "MOBILE_NO": "9000000000"}}]'

trial %>%  
    gather_array %>% # stack as an array
    spread_values(USER_ID = jstring('KEYS','USER_ID'), 
                  MOBILE_NO = jstring('KEYS','MOBILE_NO'))
```

Can also use `enter_object` if preferred or necessary:

```
trial <- '[{ "KEYS": {"USER_ID": "1266", "MOBILE_NO": "9000000000"}}]'

trial %>%  
  gather_array %>% # stack as an array
  enter_object('KEYS') %>%
  spread_values(USER_ID = jstring('USER_ID'), 
                MOBILE_NO = jstring('MOBILE_NO'))
```