# How to convert a JSONArray into a R data frame using Java?

Tags: java, r, json, rjava

Is there a way to convert a JSONArray to a R data frame using Java?

We felt it would a better way to convert a JSONArray to a R data frame, rather than writing it to a file/db and then again retrieve it from R.

Any suggestions/recommendations of libraries would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

First for working with R language in Java project you need to use some JVM-based R interpreter/interface. For instance you can look on next few options:

- [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/) - JVM-based interpreter for the R language for statistical computing;
- [rJava](https://github.com/s-u/rJava) - R to Java interface;
- [FastR](https://github.com/oracle/fastr) - an implementation of the R Language in Java atop Truffle.

Approach to converting will depend on what tool you choose.

Comment: We use rJava, but are not found a way to convert a JSON to data frame. If there is a way, please let us know...it would be great

Comment: I didn't work with rJava unfortunately, and I don't pretty well know R, but I think it will be easier to serialize JSONArray to String JSON and then process it with R approach, something like in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame.