# Turn a json list to a data frame

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe

I have a json list that its saved as text, and i'm trying to convert it into a data frame.List looks like that:

```
`{"posts": {
        "data": [
          {
            "comments": {
              "data": [
                {
                  "created_time": "2020-01-25T16:48:03+0000",
                  "message": "I love all kind of art and paintings. However 19 thousand dollars for a painting is entirely too much!!. ",
                  "id": "1579832716452874_1373756966159579"
                },
                {
                  "created_time": "2020-01-25T15:21:29+0000",
                  "message": "The wind blows a piece of paper and lands next to your house. You unravel it, \"Hey hope you are having a nice day!\"...",
                  "id": "1579832716452874_1373704542831488"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }`
```

and so on. I would like for my data frame to be split in the following columns:

```
`created_time|message|id`
```

along with their respective data.
I have tried the following command but with no success as i'm getting the same exact output:

```
` df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol=length(data), byrow = FALSE))`
```

Also because the data are saved as text, the  json packages (rjson,jsonlite) won't work. 
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "saved as text" mean? That sounds like a good thing. I'm not sure what JSON stored as something other than text would look like.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947643/getting-imported-json-data-into-a-data-frame/37739735) thread.

Comment: So using data <- fromJSON(data) i get the following error:Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Comment: Can you complete your example data so that it's syntactically valid JSON to test on? Right now it's truncated, so it's not clear what the original structure is.

Comment: @Brian updated with the complete data

Comment: @XristosSolwmou: I'm really trying to help you. However, is this really the correct JSON? As far as I get it there is one closing `]` missing and the entire string should be surrounded by `{ }`.

Comment: Hi @Gregory, sorry about that. They are a long of data and i am only including a small portion, hence the mistake when pasting the code. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you seemed to be having was with the quotation marks. If you have your JSON object saved as a text file, `{jsonlite}` will automatically escape those characters when reading the file. The defaults for `fromJSON` flatten lists into dataframes when possible, which is what you wanted.

```
x <- jsonlite::fromJSON("complex_json.json")

x_df <- x$posts$data[1]$comments$data[[1]]

tibble::as_tibble(x_df)  # tibble is for pretty-printing purposes only
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   created_time        message                                                          id                   
>   <chr>               <chr>                                                            <chr>                
> 1 2020-01-25T16:48:0~ "I love all kind of art and paintings. However 19 thousand doll~ 1579832716452874_137~
> 2 2020-01-25T15:21:2~ "The wind blows a piece of paper and lands next to your house. ~ 1579832716452874_137~
> ```

The only tricky bit is figuring out the `x$posts$data[1]$comments$data[[1]]`. I always do that interactively at the console, occasionally checking `str()` of the resulting object to see where there are hidden levels of nesting that aren't printing clearly.